# Difference between lock row and Record Currently Unavailable

Tags: apex, query, error, dml, method

Good day everyone,

Last time,I encounter this error saying :

> UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW, unable to obtain exclusive access to this record.

I try to search a possible fix and I found that adding 'For Update' keyword in the query will fix the problem. I added the said keyword in my query, but now I encounter another error saying

> The record you are attempting to edit, or one of its related records, is currently being modified by another user. Please try again.

Can you please explain what is the difference with this 2 error ? and what are the possible remedy how to get rid of this error ?

Answer (score 4):

The two errors are essentially the same thing, but one is designed to appear in Apex/API contexts, the other is meant for UI contexts (e.g. a user is editing a record in the UI). The cause is typically because of data skew, such as mentioned in [Reducing Lock Contention by Avoiding Account Data Skew](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2013/01/reducing-lock-contention-by-avoiding-account-data-skews.html). There's not necessarily a "code" solution for this, since it simply means that there's too much database contention.

## Ownership Skew

Having one user own a majority/all records of any type is more will increase contention. Try to make sure that users own the correct records as necessary. The more evenly spread out your records are, the better performance you'll get.

## Account/Master Skew

Do not place all of your child records on a single parent record. For example, do not place every Contact in your org on a single Account. The general rule of thumb is to not go over 10,000 children per parent, but you should keep accounts as small as possible.

## Minimize Transaction Time

Optimize your code to use the least amount of time possible. Use debug logs to find out which sections you need to optimize.

---

There is no "silver bullet" solution to this. You'll need to look at your code, see what it's doing, check all objects it touches (including master records for detail records), run reports for ownership skew and master/account skew, move records around as appropriate, try to optimize your triggers and any other code that uses these records (e.g. Visualforce, Lightning). Overall, it might be a simple fix, or incredibly complicated, but it's not something we can answer directly to your situation, since it would require significant analysis.

Answer (score 0):

See this article on locking: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.draes.meta/draes/draes_object_relationships_record_level_locking.htm

> In addition to taking this standard precaution, developers and administrators should know that when they are updating child records in Salesforce, **the system locks the parent and the child records** to prevent inconsistencies, such as updating a child record whose parent has just been deleted in another thread

For parent/child scenarios with a Master/Detail that have this problem, such as when triggers are adding/updating children frequently and you cannot limit the total child record counts nor prevent thread concurrency, removing the relationship as being a Master/Detail but defining it as an Id/Text field configured as an External ID is a better option.  So the scenario is you have a "parent" object and want to have a reference back to it from the children.

Salesforce will of course not lock "parent" records if the FK field is a simple Id/Text field.  This means you have to maintain the referential integrity manually of course.  And there will be no option for cascading delete.  Specifying it as an External ID will mean it can be indexed.  Since it is a parent Id reference, it obviously cannot be unique.  Also with this solution you will not be able to perform SOQL JOINS using the `__r` notation, but this is easy to work around.